# How to parse a String like "14px" to get Int value 14 in Swift

Tags: swift

I receive from a server API a String like "14px". How to transform this String to Int with value 14 ignoring substring "px"?

Comment: by stripping the "px" or the last two characters away - where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If string always come with just `px` at last you can subscript it and ignore the last 2 characters.

```
let str = "14px"  
var numStr = str.substring(to: str.index(name.endIndex, offsetBy: -2))
print(numStr) // "14"
//Now you can convert "14" to Int
print(Int(numStr))
```

**Or**

```
print(Int(String(str.characters.dropLast(2))))
```